# Unable to install PDFshuffler in ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04, installation, pdf

I am unable to install pdfshuffler in ubuntu 11.04. I am getting the following error,

```
karthick@Ubuntu-11.04:~$ sudo apt-get install pdfshuffler
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
pdfshuffler : Depends: python-poppler but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

### Update:

```
karthick@IT-Chennai:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

karthick@IT-Chennai:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick Release.gpg
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_IN
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick Release.gpg
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/universe Translation-en
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/universe Translation-en_IN
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_IN
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick Release
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick Release   
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted Sources
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick/main i386 Packages
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe Sources  
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse Sources
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main i386 Packages
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse i386 Packages
Reading package lists... Done

karthick@IT-Chennai:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: umm - your prompt says 11.04 but your sources.list says maverick (10.10)... which one are you using?  Have you done a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`?

Comment: Just I have changed the source file to maverick and tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have enabled the `universe` repository and executed these commands to install pdfshuffler. And now pdfshuffler is installed.

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install pdfshuffler`